# android multiscreen sup

Tags: android, android-layout

what I want...? For example - I have imageView which is 640*480 in resolution... I have a layout, where this imageView appears... I want this imageView to be just a 1/4 of screen on all screens: 3.7, 8, 10 inch???? How could I do it?

```
        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/s221" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `layout_weight` parameter in the view.